# Full text search with mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a search key feature. But I am not getting any result with the following query.

```
public function SearchKey($key,$userid)
{
     $key = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db, $key);
     $userid = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db, $userid); 
      
      $query = mysqli_query($this->db,"SELECT * FROM posts WHERE 
       MATCH(theKey) AGAINST('$key' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) 
       AND uid = '$userid' ORDER BY sgq_id LIMIT 5") or die(mysqli_error($this->db));
      
       while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
          $data[]=$row;
       }
       if(!empty($data)) { 
         return $data;
       }   
     
}
```

Then fetch,

```
$search = $Data->SearchKey($key, $userid);
if($search){
   foreach($search as $data){
       echo $data['theKey'];
   }
}
```

For example if I search OK005 then I can not get any results. I tried Full-text Search functions https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Anyone can help me here, what I am missing ?

[image]

Comment: Are you literally putting `'$key'` and `'$userId'` in your query, or are they placeholders that are being replaced?

Comment: @skrrp $key is searching value, $userId is loged in user id.

Comment: Ok. Print out the SQL string just before the database call is made. Please post the SQL being generated as well as the output from MySQL when you run that query against the database yourself.

Comment: When I run SQL Query from MySQL then I got correct result. :\

Comment: Can you please wrap a try-catch around your PHP database call and in the catch `var_dump($exception->getMessage());`, then post that message in your question, or the output of `mysql_error()` from just after the database call.

Comment: If this is the real code and not just retyped for the question, you mispelled a variable! `$search = $Data->SearchKey($key, $userid); if($serach){` -- note `serach`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I just misspelled it here, edited.

Answer (score 1):

You're using single quotes to pass your variables. These will not be expanded in your query. You're better off using a prepared statement, and use parameter/value bindings to pass the variables. This will also solve the problem of SQL injection that your code appears to be vulnerable to.

You can try something like:

```
// Replace comment with appropriate connection data.
$pdo = new PDO(/* your DSN etc. */);

// Your query.
$sql =
'SELECT * FROM posts WHERE ' .
'MATCH(theKey) AGAINST(? IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) ' .
'AND uid = ? ORDER BY sgq_id LIMIT 5';

// Create prepared statement from query.
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);

// Bind the values and enforce data type.
$statement->bindValue(1, $key, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(2, $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT);

// Run query.
$statement->execute();

// Get query results.
$rows = $statement->fetchAll();

// Your magic ...
```

Comment: @Azzo, please consider marking my answer as accepted if you found it valuable :).

Comment: Hi @ro-achterberg thanks for your answer but I can't display any difference here. You answered with same code you just added pdo

Comment: @Azzo, from what I understood your query didn't work in your PHP, but it did work in an SQL shell. So the problem seems to have been your PHP, which you haven't posted. Have you tried my example? If you have and it didn't work, then please post your code so we can assist you better.

Comment: OP’s query is fully valid

Comment: @LelioFaieta, my point exactly. Azzo tells us the SQL works, but his code does not. Yet he hasn't shown us any code. My answer provides at least a starting point.

Comment: @RoAchterberg Please check the question I have updated.

Comment: _You're using single quotes to pass your variables. These will not be expanded in your query_ false. the variables are correctly incapsulated. The string is sourrounded by double quotes and the single quotes are corectly just part of the string. No need for concatenation

Comment: @LelioFaieta, please keep your belligerence in check. I commented on the post before an edit was made that showed how the variables were used!

Comment: Even on the first version of the post the query was fully valid.

Comment: @LelioFaieta, I never disputed the validity of the query. Every comment you've made has been futile.